How to transfer large message(>MTU) using RDMA UD mode?
RDMA UD (Unreliable Datagram) mode support Send/Recv operation only, and with the limit that only one packet can be sent with a send wr, which causes that the transfered message's size should less than MTU at a time. I want to know why this limit exists and whether there is a way/library to support that transfer a large message with a send wr?
